# how to find the notifications limit on android programatically?

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

We have notification limit on all devices i think and they are not same on all device manufactures. Do we have any way to read this notification limit on device from our app?

Comment: You might want to explain in greater detail what you mean by "notification limit".

Comment: On some devices if we get more than some number of notifications, it wont show them, it will discard..For example on Samsung, it receives 10 messages per app, and if the user sends more notifications without clearning them from the stack, OS wont show them, it will block to show them. If user clears any messages from stack, then the new notifications will be displayed.

Comment: That is probably unrelated to Firebase Cloud Messaging. Raising excessive notifications is spam; I am not surprised that there are limits that manufacturers added. However, AFAIK, there is no way for you to determine the limit, if there is one on the device.